# Create table with default dateformat?

Tags: mysql, sql, date, import-from-csv

I am using a Load command to insert all the data in a CSV file to the mysql table. The load query sample is:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\path\\to\\windows\\file.CSV'
INTO TABLE table_name
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(field1, field2, field3, fieldx);
```

The data in the file has the following format:

> FName || LName || num1 || num2 || num3|| num4 || num5 || date

- Here all nums are of *Float* data type.
- Here the date format of date in csv file is dd-MM-yyyy.

So when loading the complete file in DB I am storing dates as a *varchar*, because when I store them in a *DATE* datatype I get 0000-00-00.

Now after inserting data I have to work on dates but I am not able to get the sorted dates as they are stored as a *Varchar*. 
Is there any way I can specify the default dateformat at the time of table creation. For example:

```
create table test (
mydates date(date : dd-mm-yyyy));
```

something like this.

Or could anyone suggest a different approach to tackle this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `str_to_date` to convert the string into a date time object and use `set` to set the column's value manually. Lets say `fieldx` is your date field:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\path\\to\\windows\\file.CSV'
INTO TABLE table_name
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(field1, field2, field3, @fieldx)
SET fieldx = str_to_date(@fieldx, "%d-%m-%Y");
```

Have a look at the [manual page for load data](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html) for more information; and adjust the format string using [this table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).

Comment: I am using str_to_date method and the data is being inserted successfully but the date columns data is coming NULL. Thanks for the manual page I am reading it to get into further details.

Comment: Date which comes from file is 10-APR-2008 and I am using "%d-%m-%Y" to convert it to sql date.

Comment: Check the format table [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format); and fix the format string.

Comment: Ah...I didn't knew that date format requires the same string (%b) in which the original date is. I thought that mysql will convert it automatically. Thanks @Burhan Khalid. Your solution works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using the "string to date" function

```
STR_TO_DATE(table.datestring, '%m-%d-%Y')
```